# Rename all files with same base name

Tags: bash, glob

When I make latex documents, multiple files are created with the same base name but a different extension.
If I want to rename the original file, I have to also rename every other file in the folder.

Is there a way to do the following?

```
mv file_basename.* file_newname.[whatever was globbed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
file_basename.a  file_basename.b  file_basename.c
```

Now, let's run the perl `rename` utility to rename the files:

```
$ prename 's/file_basename/file_newname/' *
$ ls
file_newname.a  file_newname.b  file_newname.c
```

As you can see all the files have the new name.

`prename`, sometimes called `rename`, is part of the perl package.

Note that some Linux distributions install by default a different and incompatible version.  If you have one of those, the above command will not work. For more information on which distributions come with `prename` or how to install it on your distribution, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148380/53604).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple bash script that does that (let's call it `rename-prefix`):

```
#!/bin/bash

basename="$1"
newname="$2"
for file in "$basename"*; do
    mv -iv -- "$file" "$newname${file#$basename}"
done
```

It has to be executed from the directory where the files reside. You run it like this:

```
rename-prefix file_basename. file_newname.
```